# User Signup with Laravel Passport - Password Grant

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

I know how the basic auth works for sign up/login on Laravel. However, I want to learn setting up how to do user sign up (for Password Grant). I set up Passport (2.0) - Passport Grant, and I can get token; however I couldn't find anything for user signup. Then I found a [topic here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-register-a-user-through-laravel-passport/replies/340022) explaining that I should call the `oauth/token` internally, but also couldn't figure out how to achieve it exactly.

So what I thought is creating a `signup()` method in a controller and handle user registration on my own, but then how would I pass necessary data to `oauth/token` route? Because what Laravel uses for `$request` is `Request $request` but what Passport uses is `ServerRequestInterface $request` and when I vardump the $request on `oauth/token`'s issueToken method, it's totally different `Request $request`.

```
// Setup new method
public function signup(Request $request) {

  // do validations

  // create user
  User::create([
    'email' => $request->username,
    'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
  ]);

  $client = \Laravel\Passport\Client::where('password_client', 1)->first();

  $oauthData = [
     'grant_type' => 'password',
     'client_id' => $client->id,
     'client_secret' => $client->secret,
     'username' => $request->email,
     'password' => $request->password,
     'scope' => null
  ]

  // Here, I got confused how to pass this `oauthData` to `issueToken()` route 
  // and it takes it as `ServerRequestInterface $request`

}
```

[Someone did it likes this here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-register-a-user-through-laravel-passport/replies/340022), but no idea how I should exactly implement this approach. Because my `/oauth/token` route's post method issueToken() is like this:

```
public function issueToken(ServerRequestInterface $request)
{
    return $this->withErrorHandling(function () use ($request) {
        return $this->server->respondToAccessTokenRequest($request, new Psr7Response);
    });
}
```

I am very confused and couldn't figure out how to overcome this. What is the right way of handling such scenario where I need to signup users through api?

Comment: I am confused what yo want, but you can sign up user by defining a REST endpoint that points to a controller method which resisters the user. And for login again use general passport funtionality i.e. pass username and password to get access token adn refresh token.

Comment: I actually want to return the token right after registration as a response. Otherwise the user needs to re-login after registration, am I wrong? I thought maybe I could just pass the necessary data to oauth/token route right after registration completes, so the user doesn't need to re-enter his credentials

Comment: why you want to return the token? after registration user need to pass username amd password and the dynamically generated token you need to pass to make api calls and get resources. this is what i am doing for SPA using angular app. laravel only for REST provider.

Comment: So your flow is like: 1) user enters credentials for registration, 2) get success response and gets redirected to login page 3) user re-enters his credentials in login form 4) logged in and received token. Am I right?

Comment: yes you are absolutely right, because if you wanna return access token upon registration, you need to play with the registration method. its up to you.

Comment: Thanks man! I'm gonna go your way too :)